# Apache cross compile on arm

Tags: apache, ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling

When I run "./configure --host=arm-linux --prefix=/sdcard/apr-util --with-apr=/sdcard/apache/apr --with-mysql=/sdcard/mysql".
It appears "the --with-apr parameter is incorrect. It must specify an install prefix, a build directory, or an apr-config file."
How can I solve this problem?Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use --with-included-apr and put it in srclib/apr and srclib/apr-util beneath the httpd source package.

Comment: I couldn't understand your solution clearly,Would you like to give me a more detailed solution.Thanks.